# RxJava PublishProcessor does not receive onNext

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'am fairly new to RxJava and try to build up the Model View Intent Pattern in Android. In my View (Activity) i create a PublishProcessor as follows:

```
private PublishProcessor<MviResultIntent> mPublishProcessor;
mPublishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create();
```

After the creation I'am calling a method of my presenter with the Processor as a Parameter:

```
mResultPresenter.bindIntents(mPublishProcessor);
```

What happens inside the called method:

```
        Disposable processIntents = mPublishProcessor 
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<MviResultIntent>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(MviResultIntent mviResultIntent) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    //may be ignored
                }
            });

    mCompositeDisposable.add(processIntents);
```

and in my View Class i call afterwards:

```
mPublishProcessor.onNext(new MviResultIntent.ProductsIntent());
```

The PublishProcessor inside my Presenter does not get the onNext Event I'am trying to trigger. Am i missing something? I dont receive onComplete or onError neither.

Any help is appreciated! If you need any further Information feel free to ask. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check `mPublishProcessor.hasSubscribers()` before `onNext` to verify there are actually subscriber(s) listening the time.

Comment: As you expected there are no Subscribers when i call the onNext but i have no solution by far.

Comment: You have to call that `subscribeWith` way before the event is fired.

Comment: Yes thats what im doing or at least i believe i do. I call the creation of the PublishProcessor and the bindIntents Method inside onCreate and the onNext inside onResume.

Comment: I have another similar construct where it actually works. But the hasSubscribers returns false there too. Im on the Version 2.1.10 if this might be a hint

Comment: Lars, there is no way for us to know what's wrong as we can't see into your codebase.

Comment: Yes sorry. I wish i could share a github Repo or something similar but actually im not allowed to do that. I found out that after you put the App in the background (so when onPause is triggered) everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i can't subscribe inside a non Android class on the Main Thread. When i change the

```
.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

to

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

it works.